# RSS feed image to wordpress featured image

Tags: image, wordpress, import, rss, feed

I use the Feedwordpress plugin to import this rss file: http://norbertkoreman.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
Importing works fine, except for the image.

Now as you can see, the rssfeed has an image. I want feedwordpress to import the rss file and set the image as featured image automatically.

Is there any way to do this... or is there any plugin to handle this for me which i cannot seem to find.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with that feed is the images are contained in HTML which is embedded in a  tag. This is contrary to the preferred method of using the Atom   tag to display images. You will need to find a tool to extract the HTML  tags from within the Atom  tags contained within each Atom entry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-feed-widget